# Compute pairwise t-test on 2d numpy array columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to perform pairwise t-tests on 2D array columns. What is a way to get all the pairwise combinations of columns if not with itertools?

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(20,6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid using for loops or list comprehensions you can implement the t-test using numpy broadcasting:

```py
a = np.random.randn(20,6)
n1, n2 = a.shape
# Columns mean and squared std
m = np.mean(a,axis=0)
s2 = np.square(np.std(a,axis=0, ddof=1))

# Compute the test statistic
t = (m[:,np.newaxis] - m[np.newaxis,:])/np.sqrt((s2[:,np.newaxis] + s2[np.newaxis,:])/n1)

# Compute the 2-sided p-value
df = 2*n1 - 2
p = 2 - 2*stats.t.cdf(t,df=df)
```

Checking performance with respect to naive list comprehension implementation:

```py
def t_test(a):
    n1, n2 = a.shape
    m = np.mean(a,axis=0)
    s2 = np.square(np.std(a,axis=0, ddof=1))

    t = (m[:,np.newaxis] - m[np.newaxis,:])/np.sqrt((s2[:,np.newaxis] + s2[np.newaxis,:])/n1)

    df = 2*n1 - 2
    p = 2 - 2*stats.t.cdf(t,df=df)

    return t,p


%timeit t_test(a)
213 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [[ (i,j, stats.ttest_ind(a[:,i], a[:,j])) for i in range(n2) if i <j] for j in range(n2)]
4.36 ms ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Showing that the numpy implementation is about 20x faster.

Comment: Thank you. How can I keep only the minimum pvalue from all the combinations for both ways you used?

Comment: From the numpy implementation you can do `np.unravel_index(p.argmin(), p.shape)` to get both row and column index of where the min is.
For the other solution, maybe you want to store the data in another way to be able to access the min p-value.